# How to accurately convert meters to longitude or latitude when drawing a circle

Tags: javascript, geometry, gis, latitude-longitude

Note: The problem is not specific to Leaflet, but GIS in general.

I'm trying to draw an arc on a map. I have a function to generate the polygon points and it works on a canvas for example, but not on Lng,Lat map.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to convert the inner/outer radius from Meters to degrees (as in lng/lat), what I tried so far looks more elliptic than circular.

**How to accurately convert meters to longitude or latitude at any point on earth (except the poles)?**

Here is what I tried (works) on canvas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var c2 = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
    c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
    c2.beginPath();
    
    var fromDeg = 0;
    var toDeg = 90;
    var fromRad = getAngle(fromDeg);
    var toRad = getAngle(toDeg);
    var segments = 100;
    var step = getAngle(toDeg-fromDeg)/segments;
    var x = 250;
    var y = 250;
    var outR = 250;
    var inR = 230;
    c2.moveTo(x+(Math.sin(fromRad)*inR),y-(Math.cos(fromRad)*inR));
    //c2.moveTo(x,y);
    for (var i = fromRad; i<=toRad; i=i+step){
     c2.lineTo(x+(Math.sin(i)*inR),y-(Math.cos(i)*inR));
    }
    //c2.closePath();
    for (var i = toRad; i>=fromRad; i=i-step){
     c2.lineTo(x+(Math.sin(i)*outR),y-(Math.cos(i)*outR));
    }
    c2.lineTo(x+(Math.sin(fromRad)*inR),y-(Math.cos(fromRad)*inR));
    //c2.closePath();
    c2.stroke();
});

function getAngle(deg){
 var val = 2*(deg/360);
  return Math.PI*val;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

And here is what I tried ( dosn't work well ) on Leaflet map.

```js
   var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
     osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
     osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
       maxZoom: 18,
       attribution: osmAttrib
     });

    // initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
   var map = L.map('map').setView([59.56667, 150.80000], 12).addLayer(osm);

    // Script for adding marker on map click
   L.polygon(getPolygon()).addTo(map);

   function getPolygon() {
     var fromDeg = 0;
     var toDeg = 90;
     var fromRad = getAngle(fromDeg);
     var toRad = getAngle(toDeg);
     var segments = 100;
     var step = getAngle(toDeg - fromDeg) / segments;
     var y = 150.84229;
     var x = 59.55416;
     var outR = 0.05; // <------ should be dynamic?
     var inR = 0.025; // <------ this also?
     var polygon = [];
     polygon.push([x + (Math.sin(fromRad) * inR), y + (Math.cos(fromRad) * inR)]);
     for (var i = fromRad; i <= toRad; i = i + step) {
       polygon.push([x + (Math.sin(i) * inR), y + (Math.cos(i) * inR)]);
     }
     //c2.closePath();
     for (var i = toRad; i >= fromRad; i = i - step) {
       polygon.push([x + (Math.sin(i) * outR), y + (Math.cos(i) * outR)]);
     }
     polygon.push([x + (Math.sin(fromRad) * inR), y + (Math.cos(fromRad) * inR)]);
     return polygon;
   }

   function getAngle(deg) {
     var val = 2 * (deg / 360);
     return Math.PI * val;
   }
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://unpkg.com/leaflet-arc/bin/leaflet-arc.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your original question is

> How to accurately convert meters to longitude or latitude at any point on earth (except the poles)?

But my brain reads that as

> Given a `[lat, lng]` point and a distance `d` in meters, how to calculate a second `[lat2, lng2]` point which is `d` meters away from the first point?

Which, if you know some GIS jargon, is the same as asking

> How do I solve the [direct geodesic problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid#Solution_of_the_direct_problem)?

The answer involves mathematical concepts such as ellipsoids and great circles.

But given that you're working with Javascript and Leaflet, I'll just jump to practical implementations.

If you need a super-accurate answer, you want to have a look at [the JS implementation of GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/js/), and its methods to solve the direct geodesic problem.

If you don't really care about accuracy (and specially do not care about accuracy at the poles), you want to have a look at [cheap-ruler](https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler), and specifically its `destination(p, dist, bearing)` method.

There are more solutions, like using a equidistant map projection centered on the point, or some other implementations of the geodesic problems, or some [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) trickery, or creating the geometries outside of JS with similar methods, or whatever.

This problem has been solved already, so I advise to use any of the existing solutions.

Comment: Would you look at my solution below and see if this is accurate for circle/arc radius under 100km?

Comment: It looks accurate enough. Unfortunatly I'm not an expert in geodesics, so I cannot calculate the error between your algorithm and other algorithms.

Comment: Thanks, great references.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem

```js
   var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
     osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
     osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
       maxZoom: 18,
       attribution: osmAttrib
     });

   // initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
   var map = L.map('map').setView([59.56667, 150.80000], 12).addLayer(osm);

   // Script for adding marker on map click
   L.polygon(getPolygon()).addTo(map);

   function getPolygon() {
     var fromDeg = 0;
     var toDeg = 120;
     var lat = 59.56667;
     var lon = 150.80000;
     var outR = 200;
     var inR = 180;
     var polygon = [];
     for (var i = fromDeg; i <= toDeg; i++) {
       polygon.push(getPoint(lat, lon, inR, i));
     }
     for (var i = toDeg; i >= fromDeg; i--) {
       polygon.push(getPoint(lat, lon, outR, i));
     }
     polygon.push(getPoint(lat, lon, inR, fromDeg));
     return polygon;
   }
        /*************************
        * The solution
        *************************/
   function getPoint(lat, lon, r, deg) {
     lat2 = (r / 111230) * Math.cos(deg2rad(deg));
     lat2 += lat;
     lon2 = (r / 111230) * Math.sin(deg2rad(deg));
     lon2 = lon2 * (1 / Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)));
     lon2 += lon;
     return [lat2, lon2];
   }

   function deg2rad(deg) {
     return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
   }
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```